# How to get Object keys using angular?

Tags: angular, object, key

I know this is an old question and get many solutions in stack overflow but I tried them all and didn't get any solution for this so I am posting it here.

I am having this type of object here as you can see in below picture.

[image]

I want this section heading using this object. How can i get this ?

I used Object.keys() method but didn't get success.

Is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object.keys will not work for this you have to use it like this

`this.elements[0].constructor.name`

and you will get sectionHeading object

But this will give error in **production build** like below.

> However: beware that the name will likely be different when using
>   minified code.

So you can try this solution also

```
  this.elements.forEach((ele) => {
        if(ele instanceof SectionHeading){
          // your code here
        }
      })
```